# "Recent values to use" in Toloka quality control

Tags: crowdsourcing, toloka

Can the "Recent values to use" for control tasks be set to a larger value than the current pool size to include older pools?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you can put a larger value than the current pool size. The rule will be spread to the other pools where you indicate "recent values to use" for control tasks. To make a calculation based on control task responses from all project pools, fill in the field in the rule for each pool.
In other words, image you have 3 pools. In each pool you have control tasks rule. In 1st and 3rd pool you set "Recent values to use​" = 10. In the 2nd pool you did not indicate any values for "Recent values to use​“. So the performer's "control tasks history" will include only 1st and 3rd pools.